# How to get all the results for every input file with Do loop?

Tags: function-construction

I have several images to be processed with a series of functions. The current script I have only gives me the result for the last image. How can I get all the results for every single images? Thanks in advance!

The script I have now:

```
NotebookDirectory[]
ClearAll;
files1 = FileNames["*.jpg", NotebookDirectory[]]
nfile = Length [files1]
i = 1
Do[Data = Import[files1[[i]]];
 img = Dilation[Data, DiskMatrix[5]];
 img = Binarize[img, 0.67];
 img = CurvatureFlowFilter[img, 10];
 img = EdgeDetect[img, 10];
 img = RemoveAlphaChannel[ColorNegate@ColorConvert[img, "Grayscale"]];
 pts = PixelValuePositions[img, Black, .2];
 s1 = Select[pts, #[[1]] > 0 &];
 s1 = Select[s1, #[[1]] < 100 &];
 line1 = Fit[s1, {1, x}, x];
 a = Coefficient[line1, x ^1], {i, 1, nfile}]
```

The images are like
[image]
[image]

Comment: Coding tip: `ClearALL` is not a command, so the 2nd line in your code does nothing. `ClearALL` is a function with side effects on the sequence of symbols it receives as arguments. No arguments -- no results.

Comment: What do you mean it only gives you the result for the last image?  That `a` only has the final value?  Well, you keep assigning to it.  How can it have any other value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `Do` loops. Instead, [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) your operation on a list of filenames:

```
ClearAll[process]

process[Data_] :=
 Module[{img, pts, s1, line1},
  img = Dilation[Data, DiskMatrix[5]];
  img = Binarize[img, 0.67];
  img = CurvatureFlowFilter[img, 10];
  img = EdgeDetect[img, 10];
  img = RemoveAlphaChannel[ColorNegate@ColorConvert[img, "Grayscale"]];
  pts = PixelValuePositions[img, Black, .2];
  s1 = Select[pts, 100 > #[[1]] > 0 &]; (* Note the double condition *)
  (* Note the slightly more direct method to get the slope *)
  LinearModelFit[s1, {1, x}, x]["BestFitParameters"][[2]]
]

results = process /@ Import /@ FileNames["*.jpg", NotebookDirectory[]]
```

This will return a list of results, stored in `results`, which you can access as you wish.

With the two images you provided:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
(* Out: {-0.269902, -0.227854} *)
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your solution! But I got this after copy and run the answer: "The first argument "C:\Users\Yanyao\Desktop\pic\001.jpg is neither a rectangular array nor an image." It seems process /@ should be followed by a series of images rather than the locations of the images. I tried several times and can't solve it...help appreciated!

Comment: OK, I found a solution...I added the commands below and copy all the images after 'process /@', then I got all the results I want. I will keep searching more convenient way for this...Thanks again for your help.

   `files = FileNames["*.jpg", NotebookDirectory[]]`
   `Import[#] & /@ files`